# Windows Mobile application deployment

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile

Ho do you manage deployment of applications (including upgrades) accross your GPRS/EDGE/3G/whatever wireless Windows Mobile PDA/SmartPhones farm ?

Up to now, I've always recommended Sparus Everywan manager but we've run into many problems at the last client site (~ 60 devices). I am therefore researching alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You take a look at the [Sybase Afaria](http://www.sybase.fr/detail?id=1038840) solutions, and especially the "Afaria Software Manager".